# Video isn't working on ios devices

Tags: html, ios, video

Video is not working on iOS devices. All other devices works properly

http://kalkjarlen.dk/referencer

```
`<video width="492" height="369" controls="controls" class="video">
                            <source src="/file/2546" type="video/webm">
                                <source src="/file/2545" type="video/mp4">

                        </video>`
```

It is the video at the bottom.

Does anyone know why?

Best Regards

Alex Sleiborg

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

It was because it needed .mp4 file extension. Then i worked :)

Comment: Oh, wow. That seems really strange - the MIME type should normally be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the correct format for IOS devices, they support MPEG-4 in .mp4, .mov, .m4v formats

Comment: As you can see there i both webm and mp4